# How can we implement Authorization in Auth0 for .NET 7 based Web API Project

Tags: model-view-controller, authorization, auth0, .net-7.0

Hope everyone is doing great and it's Friday.

I have a web api which is based on .NET 7. We are using Okta for Authentication and authorization.

**What we are looking For**
We have createad roles on Okta Portal. We have assigned permissions(scopes) to Web API App on Okta Portal. Associated Permissions to Roles. Roles have been assigned to Users. Based on the role of the user, when request will come from .NET7 MVC based app, access on an end point either should be denied or granted. We have decorated the methods on controllers with [Authorize("read:messages")].

**What is the issue right now?**
When we are calling the end point, the funcationality is not working as expected. But when we enable "machine to machine" configuration and select "read:messages" scope which we created, the functionality works.

Now we removed the permission "read:messages" from role and tried again. The funcnality still worked. This is strange.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using WebAPIApplication;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
});


var domain = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/";


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = domain;
    options.Audience = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By Using wrong spelling for scope, code stops working but also machine to machine permission is required
    options.AddPolicy("read:messages", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:messages", domain)));

});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

**What else was done?**
We have raised the issue on Okta blogs and Portals but no response.

Any pointers would be extremely helpful. We are in trial mode with okta at the moment.

best regards,
SPA